# How to deploy new changes of my flow to Apache Flink cluster?

Tags: apache-flink

For example I uploaded JAR with my flow and run it through Apache Flink dashboard. Then I implemented some changes in flow and want to deploy them.

Can anybody explain me step-by-step how to deploy new version of my flow to Apache Flink cluster correctly (without downtime, loosing state, etc.)? I didn't find description of deploy process in official documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want to use is the [savepoints](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/ops/state/savepoints.html) in Flink.

The steps are as follows:

- Prepare the new jar for your job
- Save the state of the currently running job using `flink savepoint <JobID>`
- Stop the job
- Start the new jar using the just created savepoint `flink run -s <pathToSavepoint> <jobJar> ...`

See also: https://www.ververica.com/blog/how-apache-flink-enables-new-streaming-applications-part-1

Comment: Flink Kubernetes operator abstracts all these and makes it a seamless process. check - https://github.com/lyft/flinkk8soperator